# Existence of a smooth time-dependent 1-form $\mu_t$ satisfying $\omega_t = d \mu_t$ for a given smooth time-dependent exact 2-form

Tags: geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, symplectic-geometry

Given a compact manifold $M$ and a smooth time-dependent exact 2-form $\omega_t$ on $M$, 
is it possible to find a smooth time-dependent 1-form $\mu_t$ on $M$ such that $\omega_t = d \mu_t$?

Related reference is in the Theorem 3.17. in Mcduff's Introduction to Symplectic Topology.

> [image]

Specifically, I'd like to know the part of the setence "The inductive step is achieved by using the Mayer-Vietoris sequence."

I tried it by using bump functions.

Let $U, V$ be open sets on which it is true for compactly supported forms. 
Let $\omega_t$ be a compactly supported closed form on $U \cup V$. 
To prove it, I take two functions $\phi, \psi$, a partion of unity subordinate to $\{ U , V \}$. However $d (\phi \omega_t) = d\phi \wedge \omega_t$ is not a closed form.

So I'd like to know how to use this hint.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you assuming that there's a smooth $2$-form $\omega$ on $I\times M$ whose restriction to $\{t\}\times M$ is $\omega_t$?

Comment: @TedShifrin Sorry. $\omega$ is not a 2-form on $I\times M$. I made my question more specifically.

Comment: Well, what does a "smooth family" of forms mean?

Comment: @TedShifrin I interpret $\omega$ is a smooth function $I\times M \rightarrow \Lambda^2 (T^*M)$  where $I\times M $ and $\Lambda^2 (T^*M)$ are viewed as smooth manifolds and $\omega_t$, the restriction to $\{ t \} \times M$,  is 2-form on $M$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $U,V$ are two open sets with non-empty, connected intersection, $\omega_t$ an exact two form on $U\cup V$ and $\xi $ a smooth function on $U\cup V$ satisfying $$\xi(x)=\begin{cases}1 &x\in U\setminus V\\ 0&x\in V\setminus U\end{cases}$$

Let $\sigma_t $ be a primitive of $\omega_t$ on $U$ and $\lambda_t$ a primitive on $V$. Now define $$\theta_t (x) :=\xi(x)\sigma_t +(1-\xi(x))\lambda_t $$

Note that $\omega_t -d \theta_t $ is a closed form and it is supported on $U\cap V$. By the Poincare Lemma we can find a primitive $\alpha_t$ of $\omega_t -d \theta_t$. Since the support of $\alpha_t$ is in $U\cap V$. Therefore $$\theta_t +\alpha_t $$ defines a smooth primitiv of $\omega_t$ on $U\cup V$.